# How to trigger an event ONLY if both dropdowns are selected?

Tags: javascript, select, jquery

I have a dropdown select list on my page of class="TypeFilter".

I have a jQuery event that fires when a value in that list is selected.

```
$(".TypeFilter").change(function() 
{
    // Extract value from TypeFilter and update page accordingly
));
```

I now have to add another list to the page, and I want to implement functionality which will prevent the `.change(function()` from running unless both are selected.

In both lists the first option in the list is some text instructing the user to select one of the items, so I was thinking of just writing some logic to test that both lists have a selected index greater than 0.

I think this is a touch unclean though, especially considering that other pages that have a TypeFilter use the same logic.

Is there any nifty functionality in jQuery that can do this?

**edit** I should specify that the user needs to be able to update the page by selecting either dropdown, so I can't put the onchange on the second element and test that the first element has a selected value, as suggested in one of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind the same event to all dropdowns, you can get a collection of all the dropdowns and check that all of them are selected. Example:

```
$('.Dropdown').change(function(){
  var elements = $('.Dropdown');
  if (
    elements.filter(function(){
      return this.selectedIndex > 0;
    }).length == elements.length
  ) {
    // all dropdowns are selected
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is indeed nifty!! :-) One thing though - that `;` at the end of `}).length == elements.length;` is misplaced. It shouldn't be there. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dave: Yes, you are right, the semicolon should not be there. :)

Comment: I don't want to sound grumpy that you didn't like my solution :), but isn't @Guffa's solution exactly the one that you wanted to avoid?

Comment: @snowlord: Well, yes, because there is no way around it. The only reason that your answer doesn't contain a similar test is that you avoided to implement the test at all. ;)

Comment: Oh, OK, I saw the test as trivial, sorry. I thought you wanted a way to implement the change-function *without* the test built-in, to make it more general. Hence my solution, where you don't need to send in the test at all if it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

As you partly mention, put the onchange on the second element and test that the first element has a selected value before you fire off any logic.

Comment: but the user needs the capability of updating the page by changing either dropdown.. I'll update the question to specify. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead, and as the eventdata, send a function that checks that either that both are selected or that the other is selected. Untested code:

```
function checker() {
    // test your conditions
}

$(".TypeFilter").bind('change', {test: checker}, function(event) 
{
    if (event.data.test && event.data.test()) {
        // Extract value from TypeFilter and update page accordingly
    }
));
```

This way the other pages that use the same function will not notice any changes.